# Nativescript MainActivity navigation not working after resuming custom activity

Tags: android, nativescript

I started a custom activity using `app.android.foregroundActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, result_code)` and on exit of it the main activity navigation does not work and sometimes UI and button click events not working as well.

Am using nativescript 5.4.2

I tried modifying the application.android.js in tns modules folder onActivityResumed method and set foregroundActivity but no avail.

```
 onActivityResumed: profiling_1.profile("onActivityResumed", function (activity) {
            androidApp.foregroundActivity = activity;
            androidApp.notify({ eventName: ActivityResumed, object: androidApp, activity: activity });
        })
```

Below is the link to the custom activity I created.

https://github.com/MohammedBashiru/nativescript-expresspay/blob/master/src/expresspay-browser-switch-activity.ts

Below is a link to short video of the error
https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com/files/UJBGAJEKD/FMFK8MGSY/error.mov

I expect that on exit of the custom activity I should resume back to MainActivity and everything should work as expected as in Native Android.

Comment: You are not suppose to implement `setActivityCallbacks` in your custom activity. Only your main activity should do that.

Comment: Thank you @Manoj for your reply. In this case how do I handle callbacks from the custom activity especially onBackPressed

Comment: You do it in the native way by overriding the `onBackPressed()` method in Activity. Callbacks are meant to be used only by the main activity as the framework uses them. Your custom activity operates outside the core framework, so you handle that yourself.

Comment: Ok so that means I would just comment out all lines with ```this._callbacks``` and it should work right ?

Comment: @Manoj can you show me an example. I tried commenting the ```setActivityCallbacks``` and I got an error ```Cannot read property 'onCreate' of undefined```

Comment: You have to remove anything related to callbacks, that includes the next line too, `this._callbacks.onCreate(this, savedInstanceState, super.onCreate);`.

Comment: @Manoj Thank you again for the help.

I commented all callbacks and got this error

```Dynamically loading class com.android.webview.chromium.ContentSettingsAdapter was unsuccessful. Will attempt to load class from alternative ClassLoader.

android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.arktivetour.mohammedbashiru/com.expresspaygh.api.ExpressPayBrowserSwitchActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()```